# How do I properly use TransactionScope with Nunit

Tags: c#, mysql, transactionscope, nunit-3.0

I am attempting to do some integration testing on my Data Access Layer object.

I am using C#, Nunit3 and MySQL 5.7.

Here is my code.

```
    [TestCase("payee", 0)]
    [TestCase("payee", 53)]
    [TestCase("payee_to_corp_to_permissions", 0)]
    [TestCase("payee_to_corp_to_permissions", 53)]
    [Test]
    public void AllRecordsToMigrateTest(string tableName, decimal corpId)
    {
        using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            List<Payee> payees = new List<Payee>
            {
              new Payee { payee_id = 1, corp_id = 1 },
              new Payee { payee_id = 2, corp_id = 53 },
              new Payee { payee_id = 3, corp_id = 22, payee_type_id = 3 },
              new Payee { payee_id = 4, corp_id = 1 },
            };

            using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(DstConnectionString))
            {
                mySqlConnection.Open();
                foreach (var payee in payees)
                {
                    payee.Insert(mySqlConnection);
                }
                PayeeToCorpToPermission payeeToCorpToPermission = new PayeeToCorpToPermission { payee_id = 4, corp_id = 53 };
                payeeToCorpToPermission.Insert(mySqlConnection);
            }

            DataTable result = dbConnect.AllRecordsToMigrate(adilasMySQLTable, 53);

            Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Rows.Count);
        }
    }
```

The if I run the cases separately they all execute properly, but when I run them together I get a primary key conflict on payee_id for all test cases after the first.

dbConnect opens it's own connection to the same server as the setup code but does not modify anything just queries.